# How to hide an iframe in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, iframe, popup

I am showing an AJAX window in an iframe.  I want the user to be able to click on the Close button that is in the and close the window.  This seemed to work at first, but when I try to show the window again, it's gone:

```
function closeme() {
   if (parent.document.getElementById ("ifFundingSources")) {    // clear the content of iframe if it's there

      var iframe = parent.document.getElementById ('ifFundingSources');
      iframe.parentNode.removeChild (iframe);
   }
}
```

So I guess I need to hide the iframe rather than remove it?  If so, how do i do that?

EDIT:  I found that I can hide it like this:

```
parent.document.getElementById ('ifFundingSources').style.display = "none";
```

However, it's still hidden when I open the window up again next time.  All I'm really trying to do is close the window with a button on the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your element visible like this:

```
parent.document.getElementById ('ifFundingSources').style.display = "block";
```

Do that every time you open the window.

Comment: Stupid question here, but I am just getting my feet wet with JavaScript (old Winforms developer here)... where do I do that?

Comment: I'd have to see your source to be able to tell you that, but you could call it an onClick event attribute, for example let's pretend you have an image acting as your button:

`<img href='./mybutton.png' onClick='unHide();'>`

Before calling a function, you will of course have to define it:

`<script>
function unHide(){
      parent.document.getElementById ('ifFundingSources').style.display = "block";
}
</script>`

Or you can do something like this:
`<img href='./mybutton.png' onClick='function(){ parent.document.getElementById ('ifFundingSources').style.display = "block"; };'>`